# how to make and iframe appear and include it in joomla

Tags: javascript, iframe, joomla, href

Here's the plot:
I have an iframe that initially is hidden and situated in the  far left

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="position:absolute;right:15;bottom:-10"    style="visibility:hidden;" width="600" height="480" frameborder="0" align="right" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I have a javascript function that dynamically make the iframe visible and update it's src

```
<script>
function ShowFrame(id) {

var iframe = document.getElementsById('myFrame')
  iframe.style.display='block'    
}
switch(id)
{
case "001": iframe.src= "www.google.com"
case "002": iframe.src= "www.yahoo.com"
}
</script>
```

and a link like

```
<a href="#" id="001" onclick="ShowFrame(this.id);"> First site </a>
<a href="#" id="001" onclick="ShowFrame(this.id);"> Second site </a>
```

I'm trying to make it work in Joomla, ive turned off the Tiny editor, and save the code but it won't work ? any leads?

Comment: Try turning TinyMCE back on via the Plugin Manager. Then go into the options for TinyMCE and you will find `script,applet,iframe` inside the **Prohibited Elements**. Try removing **iframe** from there

Comment: What does not work? Is the HTML code removed or did the site crash?

Comment: The iframe does not appear when i click on the link ?? is my code correct i'm not quite confortable with javascript ?

Comment: Where i should add my javascript ???!

Comment: How dynamic does this need to be? if it is relatively fixed just put it in a wrapper module and loadposition the module.

Comment: when first the user open the page, the iframe is loaded and is hidden by default and when the user click on a hyperlink the iframe appear, my problem is when i click the link the iframe does not appear ! i put a script in the page but that won't work